# modal dialog not close

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, web-applications, modal-dialog

### RegistrationPage.aspx

```
function btnSearchClick()
{
    if (window.showModalDialog)
    {
        window.showModalDialog(
            "Search.aspx", 
            "Search Patient", 
            "dialogWidth:800px; dialogHeight:400px"
        );
        return false;
    }
}
```

### Search.aspx

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("input[id$='btnAdd']").live('click', function (e) {                   
        hidID.value = $.trim($('table td.csstablelisttdselected:first').text());
        return true;
    });
});
```

### Seach.aspx.cs

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("RegistrationPage.aspx?ID=" + hidID.Value, true);
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
        this.GetType(), 
        "CloseScript", 
        "window.close()", 
        true
    );
}
```

In `RegistrationPage.aspx` page on click of `button` search pop up dialog box.
In `Search page` i am getting id in `hiddenfield` and redirect to `registration page`.
When I click on btn add then dialog not close and it redirect to registration page within dialog.

**Please dont give answer like "use jquery dialog box","or use another dialog control"**

Comment: have you trid closing first then redirect?

Comment: yes i have tried but same thing happens " dialog not close and it redirect to registration page within dialog."

Comment: What is your dialog in html? Div? Iframe?

Comment: In html...............

Comment: You say "it opens in the modal windows" - sounds like an iFrame to me, might be a source of the problem - you should know what your software is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tested example :

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function btnSearchClick()
        {
            window.returnValue = undefined;
            var result = window.showModalDialog("Search.aspx", window, "dialogHeight:650px; dialogWidth:900px;");
            if (result == undefined)
                result = window.returnValue;
            if (result != null && result != "undefined")
                alert(result);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <input type="button" id="btnOpen" onclick="btnSearchClick();" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Search.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Search.aspx.cs" Inherits="Search" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function CloseModal() {
            if (window.opener) {
                window.opener.returnValue = 'your return value';
            }

            window.returnValue = 'your return value';
            self.close();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Search.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

public partial class Search : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CloseScript", "closescript()", true);

    }
}
```

So instead of redirect your user you could pass a value from Modal to Opener.

Here another example : [Modal Dialog ReturnValue](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/showmodaldialog-returnvalue-is-undefined-in-google-chrome/)

Hope can help.

Comment: I've changed the answer and posted a full example. take a look.